# Real life generic class examples

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, generics, singleton

I got next question at Java interview:

1. Could you name some generic class examples from real life? Not from real PROGRAMMING life, but in common. E.g. you are explaining generics to person, who doesn't know anything about programming.
2. Same thing about the most easy design pattern - singleton.

I have know any idea, about first question (about generics), I tried to name different hand tools (like fretsaw), which work with only one type of material, but it is not generics really.

Please, avoid collection-like suggestions, it is too naive and obvious.

Comment: Dictators are a pretty good singleton. You can have only one per country, and they're bad practice in general. :)

Answer (score 7):

1. I want to open a pet shop, I don't care what different type of pets they are but dammit I want a pet shop.  I want kittens, tortoises and spiders.  I want to be able to count them up, find how many animals I've got and order them as such.  I don't want to have to cast the fact my tortoise is a tortoise, I know it's a tortoise.
2. There is only one shop bank account, I will never have more than one, where ever someone orders from me, either online or by post, there is only ever one shop bank account.  There can never be another no matter where my shop is accessed from.

Answer (score 0):

A bowl of something is always a good example.

```
Bowl<T> can be Bowl<Cookie> Bowl<Candy> ....
```

Comment: So, you are not able to put any candy in bowl of cookies?

Comment: You could, but imagine a shelf filled with bowls. Each bowl is the same (size, shape etc.) and is handled in the same way (put sth. in, take the top item from it). But they are labelled Cookie, Candy, etc. . You want to be sure, that if you take sth. out of the Cooki bowl, it is indeed a Cookie - and not a candy. In this scenario you wouldn't want to have a candy in the cookie bowl, although you could technicallly put it there. Generics offer you that "typesafety".

Answer (score 0):

So I want to buy a TV. I am looking through a `List<TV>`. But then I decide that I want to get an LCD TV. So I `instanceof` through the list and get `List<LCD_TV>`. Since I want a Company tv, I call abstract `TV.getManufacturer()` and check if it `== company`. Then I know I want a LED lighted LCD, so I call `LCD_TV.getLcdType()` and check if it `== LED`. Then I just choose randomly `list.get( rand() % list.size() )`